# Ubuntu(LTS 14.4.3) won't boot after installation

Tags: boot

I installed Ubuntu 14.4.3 LTS in my home PC(gigabyte motherboard, AMD phenon X2 Processor and 4GB ram) but when i try to start in the next morning it won't start, stuck with "initramfs" prompt.

Comment: i installed several times, but when i tried to boot in next morning it won't boot. It shows "AMD Data Change..."  and ends up in "initramfs" prompt. sometimes when i used live CD and run "boot-repair", it will work. but next morning it won't boot.

Comment: What is your graphics adapter? Did you install drivers for it? How?